# Mysql function to split csv?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a `mysql` function that can split a csv line and extract the value at a specific index:

```
RETURN
    substring_index(
        substring_index(csv, ';', pos),
    ';', -1)
```

This works in general:

```
SPLIT("my;string", 1) -> returns 'my' 
SPLIT("my;string", 2) -> returns 'string'
```

But: how can I return an empty value if the `pos` is not present at all?

```
SPLIT("my", 5) -> returns 'my', but should return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a function, which appear to work...

```
RETURN 
CASE WHEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputStr, delim, pos), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputStr, delim, pos -1)) + 1), delim, '') = inputStr 
THEN '' 
ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputStr, delim, pos), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputStr, delim, pos -1)) + 1), delim, '')
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended as follows. But if anybody knows a function without having to run a `REPLACE` over the csv string, I'd still be grateful for your response.

```
RETURN
CASE WHEN LENGTH(csv) - LENGTH(REPLACE(csv, ';', '')) + 1 >= pos
THEN substring_index(substring_index(csv, ';', pos), ';', -1)
ELSE ''
END
```